# java.io.StreamCorruptedException on ObjectInputStream while wrapping it on CipherInputStream in Java

Tags: java, sockets, encryption

I am sending encrypted object over a socket(single client single server). The client sends the encrypted object as Sealed Object and server decrypts the object. But during the creation of ObjectInputStream on server side, it throws a StreamCorruptedException.
I have a searched a lot on the internet and my code looks fine but I don't know why the exception is being thrown.

Here is the Client class:

```
package sample;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.SealedObject;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {
    private static Socket socket;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        socket=new Socket("127.0.0.1",7777);
        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        CipherOutputStream cos=new CipherOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(),cipher);
        ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(cos);
        oos.flush();
        SealedObject sealedObject=new SealedObject("SampleString",cipher);
        oos.writeObject(sealedObject);
    }
}
```

Here is my Server class:

```
package sample;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.SealedObject;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public static SecretKeySpec sks;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        serverSocket=new ServerSocket(7777);
        Socket clientSocket=serverSocket.accept();
        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        CipherInputStream cis=new CipherInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream(),cipher);
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(cis); //line 23
        SealedObject so=(SealedObject) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println((String)so.getObject(cipher));
    }
}
```

And the following exception is thrown on the server side when client is connected:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720019
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:857)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at sample.Server.main(Server.java:23)
```

Comment: Why are you encrypting twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the double encryption. The Cipher in the output case has to seal the object and then encrypt the stream, but the Cipher object in the input case has to decrypt the stream and then unseal the object, which is the opposite order.

Remove either the `SealedObject` or the cipher streams.